# How to owerwrite directory with tar?

Tags: linux, shell, tar, archive

I want to extract files with tar so that the whole directory will be owerwritten.
I added `--overwrite-dir` but still old files in `test` dir remains.
For the test, I have `/home/ubuntu/f1/test/first.log` and `/home/ubuntu/f2/test/second.log`

Then I run in `/home/ubuntu/f1`

`tar  cvf - ./test | sudo  tar  -C /home/ubuntu/f2 --overwrite-dir -xvf -`

And with `ls /home/ubuntu/f2/test` expect to see only second.log file. But instead I get both.
Is it possible to do just with tar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter you are looking for is `--recursive-unlink`

> --recursive-unlink     empty hierarchies prior to extracting directory

```
tar  cf - ./test | sudo  tar  -C /home/ubuntu/f2 --overwrite-dir --recursive-unlink -xf -
```

Comment: this is it, it works without `--overwrite-dir`, what actually `--overwrite-dir` do?

Comment: From `man tar`: `overwrite metadata of existing directories when extracting (default)`, meaning this is the default behavior.